# how to create a file manager like CKFinder - MoxieManager with Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, ckfinder, file-manager

I want to create an ajax file manager like [CKFinder](http://cksource.com/ckfinder) and [MoxieManager](http://www.moxiemanager.com/) using Asp.Net!

can anyone help me how to start ? 
please suggest me some useful references , components and tips ...

If there is an open source project like what I need, please let me know.

Comment: This question is way too broad, those kinds of software are not as simple as you might think. That being said, have a look at https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager - it has some nice features but nothing close the CKF though.

Answer (score 0):

You first start with a simple file manager (no ajax), that simple reads the files from the disk and renders them on a page. If you place all that inside an iframe dialog, then you have something like ajax for your page.

Some examples with the code and details:
[Simple-Web-File-Manager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68901/Simple-Web-File-Manager)
[Web File Manager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8881/Web-File-Manager)
[ASP.NET User Control: File Browser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301328/ASP-NETUser-Control-File-Browser)

and you can call them from your page, using the [highslide iframe dialog content](http://highslide.com/) example.

After you make that and you have some knowledge you can move to ajax (if you still need it)